# Restart my delta loading after delete the infopackage in PSA by mistake

Tags: business-intelligence, sap-bw

I have got one issue. Can some one please help me to resolve this?

I was trying to extract some data to data source 0FI_AP_6...

then in InfoPackage Monitor I can see like..

> -->Requests (messages): Everything OK
>
> -->Extraction (messages): Everything OK
>
> -->Transfer (IDocs and TRFC): Missing messages or warnings
>
> -->Info IDoc 2 : sent, not arrived ; IDoc ready for dispatch (ALE service)
>
> ```
>      Data Package 1 : 23752 Records arrived in BW
>
>      Data Package 2 : 15216 Records arrived in BW
>
>      Request IDoc : Application document posted
>
>      Info IDoc 1 : Application document posted
>
>      Info IDoc 3 : Application document posted
>
>      Info IDoc 4 : Application document posted
> ```
>
> -->Processing (data packet): Everything OK
>
> ```
>   Data Package 1 ( 38672 Records ) : Everything OK
> ```

in Status Menu I am having message like...

> Missing data packages for PSA Table
>
> Diagnosis
>
> Data packets are missing from PSA Table . BI processing does not
> return any errors. The data transport from the source system to BI was
> probably incorrect.
>
> Procedure
>
> Check the tRFC overview in the source system.
>
> You access this log using the wizard or following the menu path
> "Environment -> Transact. RFC -> Source System".
>
> Error handling:
>
> If the tRFC is incorrect, resolve the errors listed there.
>
> Check that the source system is connected properly to BI. In
> particular, check the remote user authorizations in BI.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue...

thanks in advance for your help and quick reply is much appreciated.

**But what the worst thing is I deleted the infopackage in PSA by mistake.
In the normal case, if I repeat the process again, the delta load would be OK, but now the delta load remains error.**

so gurus,

1. **How can I restart my delta loading correctly?**
2. **I want to modify the timestamp in the delta table, but how to do it ?**

Comment: I am trying to get a SAP deticated stack page started. If you are interested please check out the pre-beta release here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to T-Code RSA7 in the source system. This will tell you the date/timestamp that the delta is set to. If the date was changed to a range that no longer works then you will need to re-initialize the datasource in the BW system side. However, the Delta date may still be fine becauase it may have never been changed when you tried to first do your load because of the connection issues.

You can create a new  infopackage and set the update to Initialize Datasource with Data Transfer. This will essentially run a full load from the datasource and then reset the delta pointer date/timestamp to when you ran it. This way you will capture all the data that you needed and anything that was already in the PSA should be overwritten.

Also note that you should delete or set the request status to red on the previous request that may contain bad data in the PSA.

From the original error it seems like you are having an RFC connection issue between the datasource and BW. Contact your BASIS support and have them check the connection to make sure it is good. To ensure that your datasource is extracting properly you can run t-code RSA3 on it in the source system. This will ensure that the extraction of data is working properly.